# How can high level features be concatenated with low level features in a CNN using keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to pass and concatenate the output of one layer to another layer in a CNN as shown in the following image. 30x30x512 layer is concatenated with 15x15x1024 after reshaping.

[image]

Please note that two different models and merging them is not the solution I am looking for. I am want to know how I can use the same model to merge the mentioned layers.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the output tensors of both layers you want to merge. Once you have these tensors there are at least two ways to merge them:

1. Using [`Reshape`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer where you can specify the output shape and the job is done.
2. By using [`tf.space_to_depth`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_depth) function and packing it to a `Lambda` layer (as it's TensorFlow operation). This might be only used when you use TensorFlow backend.

Once you have your output reshaped you can use [`concatenate`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate_1) layer and merge outputs by channels dimension.